# Functorial definition of continuous map

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

My motivation for this question is pure abstract nonsense, but I'd like to define continuous maps or continuity itself in a functorial/categorical way, since every continuous map induces a map (of sets) between the topologies in the opposite direcction.

Therefore, I could say that a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ is just a map of sets, which induces a map $f^*:Top(Y)\to Top(X)$. The thing is that given a set, there are lots of topologies on it and given two topological spaces there are in general plenty of continuous maps, so I've thought of taking a subcategory $S$ of **Set$\times \mathbf{Set}^{op}$** whose pairs consist of a set and a topology on it. In this setting, I consider a functor $F:S\to \mathbf{Set}$ which is the second projection on objets, and sending each arrow $(x,t(x))\to (y,t(y))$ to an arrow $t(y)\to t(x)$. In the best case this would give a class of continuous maps $x\to y$, but I'm not sure that every map $t(y)\to t(x)$ gives rise to a well-defined map $x\to y$.

Are there definitions of continuity or other topological concepts following this approach?

Comment: I think you might be interested in the notion of [frame](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/frame).

Comment: Thanks, I just read today that a topological space is a set with a frame of open sets.

Comment: Where did contravariancy disappear? $S$ should rather be a subcategory of ${\bf Set}\times{\bf Set}^{op}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: That's right @Berci